# C# standard library to execute in client side MVC .netcore3.1 application

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a library written in C# standard2.1 and I want to use it in server side in various components/microservices which is OK but also in client side on browser.(I don't want to have two identical versions that I need to maintain, one in C# and one in JS).

My client side application is in MVC .netcore3.1 and this is the place I want, if its possible, to use the library in one of my views. Actually to be able to call a function of this library from JS in the frond end, but I don't want to make a remote call back to the server in order to use it, somehow the C# library needs to be in the browser in some form and use it directly with JS in the client-side.

I have heard and read about Blazor these days but I haven't found a solution to my case. Did anyone  encounter a similar situation and found a solution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The solution here is Blazor. You need to read more about it.

Comment: "written in C# standard2.1" you mean targetting .Net Standard 2.1!

Answer (score 0):

can you use .Net 5.0

Microsoft's .NET 5.0 has received its first release candidate. Also included are the first RCs for ASP.NET Core 5 and EF Core 5. Blazor WebAssembly, in particular, comes up with some new features and a general improvement in performance in runtime.

for more info can you see

[link](https://github.com/danroth27/BlazorNet5Samples)

see this link about .NET 5: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/